# What is wrong with my R for loop? matrix access being reduced to vector

Tags: r, for-loop

First time using R, I am trying to populate each row of a matrix of zeroes (mm) with a vector (wolo[[9]]) that changes in every iteration of the loop because it is a function of my dataframe.

```
for (i in 1:length(foo.squared)) { 
     wolo <- tegarch(googler, skew = FALSE, asym = FALSE)   
     mm[i,]<- wolo[[9]]
     googler <- googler[-(2659-i),]     
}
```

Why do I get this error message?

Error in googler[-(2659 - i), ] : incorrect number of dimensions

The number of dimensions is correct if I type

```
 googler <- googler[-(2659-1),]
```

into the console it works fine.

My function does not change googler, so I suspect there is something more basic I am doing very wrong.

Comment: What are the values of `length(foo.squared)` and `nrow(googler)`? What is the value of `i` for which the error occurs?

Comment: length(foo.squared)  is 50 and nrow(googler) is 2660.  But after I run this loop and get the error the nrow(googler) is NULL.

Comment: what is the value of `ncol(googler)` ? If it is 1, then your data.frame (matrix ?) is converted to a vector after the first loop "turn" hence the error in dimension

Comment: I'm thinking, It must be the function tegarch that changes googler because the value of i for wich the error occurs is 2.

Comment: ncol(googler) is also NULL after i run the loop

Comment: googler is obtained by  googler <- read.csv('realgooglelogreturns.csv', sep = ";"), so it should be a data frame?

Comment: @user48259, I'd doubt it because you're not assigning anything back to googler so, except if your doing global assignment in the function `tegarch`, I'd vote for the "only one column problem" I mentionned in my previous comment. In this case, just replace your line by `googler <- googler[-(2659-i), , drop=F]` to keep your structure

Comment: what is `ncol(googler)` before you run the loop ?

Comment: @CathG this line worked googler <- googler[-(2659-i), , drop=F]. Thank you! but I still don't get what was happening...

Comment: @user48259. if you don't tell `R` to keep your 1-column object as it is with `drop=F` (which means "don't drop a dimension" or "don't simplify my object even if you can"), then `R` simplifies to a vector, which doesn't have either `row`or `column` (hence the `NULL`) but only a `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `googler` only have one column so you can try to replace the last line in your loop by:

```
googler <- googler[-(2659-i), , drop=F]
```

to keep the structure of `googler` as `data.frame` or `matrix` (prevent it from being converted to a `vector`).

Comment: Thanks again, what is the reason of the conversion and when does it happen?

Comment: @user48259. You're welcome, as I say in my last comment, when not told otherwise, `R` tends to simplify object (a vector is simpler than a matrix), for reason of efficiency.